# Create two subclasses for checking and saving accounts. A checking account has an overdraft limit but a savings account cannot be overdrawn

Tags: java, subclass, abstract

Account class was defined to model a bank account. An account has the properties account number, balance, annual interest rate, and date created, and methods to deposit and withdraw funds.

Now Create two subclasses for checking and saving accounts. A checking account has an overdraft limit(say $1,000 with a $25 fee charged), but a savings account cannot be overdrawn.

Write a test program that creates objects of Account, SavingsAccount, and CheckingAccount and invokes their toString() method.

Above are the instructions and below is my code. I cannot figure out how to invoke the  subclasses into the main Account Class. I would also like to know how the toString() method can be applied because I cannot get that either. I also kept most of my comments in my code where I was trying different ideas.

---

```
/* 

//Calls both subclasses to the main. As well as a few other variables.  
SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount();
CheckingAccount checking = new CheckingAccount();
Account account;


    double balance = 0.0;
    double withdrawal = 0.0;
    double deposit = 0.0;

    System.out.println(checking);
    CheckingAccount.getwithdrawal(10.50);
    System.out.println(savings);
    SavingsAccount.deposit(5.0);
    System.out.println(account);
     }    
}

 */

 package account;



  public class Assignment5  {

   SavingsAccount savings = new SavingsAccount();
   CheckingAccount checking = new CheckingAccount();
   Account account;

   public static void main (String[] args) {
   Account account = new Account(1122, 20000);

  /* System.out.print("After Creation,  " );
   Print (account.getBalance());
  Account.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);
   System.out.print("After Withdrawal of $2,500,  " );
   account.withdraw(2500);
   Print (account.getBalance());
    System.out.print("After Deposit of $3,000,  " );
    account.deposit(3000);
   Print (account.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Balance is " + account.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Monthly interest is " +
  account.getMonthlyInterest());
    System.out.println("This account was created at " +
  account.getDateCreated()); */

    } 
  // Extra Print Method
     public static void Print (double x){
     System.out.printf("The current balance is "+" $ "+"%4.2f"+"%n",x);
    }
  }



  class Account {
  private int id;
   double balance;
   private static double annualInterestRate;
   private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  public Account() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  public Account(int newId, double newBalance) {
     id = newId;
     balance = newBalance;
     dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
   }

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
      }

   public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
    }

     public static double getAnnualInterestRate() {
      return annualInterestRate;
      }

    public void setId(int newId) {
     id = newId;
     }

    public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
     balance = newBalance;
     }

  public static void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
  }

 public double getMonthlyInterest() {
   return balance * (annualInterestRate / 1200);
 }

  public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
   return dateCreated;
  }

   public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance -= amount;
 }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
   }
  }
```

---

```
 package account;

 public class CheckingAccount extends Account {


double overDraft = -1000;

    public void checking(double i) {

        //initializes double variable balance as 0.0
        double balance = 0.0;
        if (balance - i < overDraft){
                System.out.println("Failure: Can't overdraft more than            $1,000. A $25 +"
                        + "overdraft fee will be issued to your account. ");
             balance = balance - 25; }
        else
            balance = balance - i;
      }   
  }
```

---

```
  package account;

  public class SavingsAccount extends Account{
    double overdraftLimit = 0;

    public void withdraw (double w) {
        if (balance - w < overdraftLimit)
                System.out.println("Insufficient Funds");
        else
            balance = balance - w;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by invoking subclasses, but the signature for the toString method is

```
public String toString(){
}
```

Since everything is virtual in Java by default, then simply have that method in the subclasses to override it. From what I can guess, it seems like the question wants you to call the various methods in the toString method and return a complete string of all the information needed.

On another note, to call a superclass method even if the subclass overrides it in Java, the syntax is

```
super.function()
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to create the default constructor for a savings account and checking account.  Then you need to create an overloaded constructor (assuming you will be passing unique extra values into the subclasses)

```
 public savingsAccount() {
super();
}
//overloaded constructor
public savingsAccount(int newId, double newBalance, int anotherVariable ) {
 super(newID, newBalance);
 this.anotherVariable = anotherVariable; //this is unique to this specific class

}
```

As for toString(), you need each subclass to have its own.

```
String toString(){
 String x = "Savings: " + totalSavings + ". And the fee's assessed are: " + fees";
  return x;
}
```

This will allow you to call `savingsAccount.toString();` which will print the information.

Comment: the void function toString is not called by default, it's unlikely that this is the intention.

Comment: you would also likely want to return it instead of printing it :)

Comment: you may need to add `@Override` above the `public String toString()` depending upon the IDE you are using

Comment: you are correct, you need to return it because of the `String` type declaration

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you can just use System.out.println(savingsAccount), as it's called by default :)

Comment: Now for yours @tmaxxcar, do I keep what I had for my savingsAccount or do I replace the whole thing?

Comment: @Ben You can keep what you have and insert the code that I have provided.  Don't forget to set your `toString()` method to print the information required

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default toString method of each class
For example, in Account class

```
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "Id: "+ getId() +
                     "\nBalance:  " + getBalance()+
                     "\nAnnual Interest Rate: " + getAnnualInterestRate() +
                     "\n Monthly Interest: " + getMonthlyInterest() +
                     "\n Created on: " + getDateCreated();

        return str;
    }
```

Then, create Account object in main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Account account = new Account(1122, 20000);
    System.out.println(account); // invoke toString method in Account class
}
```

the result will be: 
Id: 1122
Balance:  20000.0
Annual Interest Rate: 0.0
 Monthly Interest: 0.0
 Created on: Thu Feb 18 15:16:47 PST 2016

Similarly, You need to override toString method for subclass also. But you need to connect superclass's toString by using super keyword:

```
public String toString()
{
    String str=super.toString();// call superclass's toString()
    str+="...";
    return str;
}
```